# How to execute response after asynchrous call made using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to send response after executing one asynchronous call using Node.js and MongoDB. I am explaining my code below.

```
 module.exports.getDashboardDetail = async(req, res, next) =>{
    console.log('Inside dashboard controller');


    var customerVisited=await Allocation.collection.aggregate([ 
    {$match:{}},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned.feedback_detail"},
    {$group:{
    _id:"total_feedback",
    count:{$sum:1}
    }
    }
    ])
    .toArray((err,docs)=>{
        if (!err) {
            customerVisited=docs
            console.log('custm',customerVisited);
        }else{
            console.log('err',err);
        }
    })
    var fosdata=await User.collection.countDocuments({},function(err,docs){
        if (!err) {
            fosdata=docs;
            //res.send(data);
            //console.log('nos of users',docs);
        }
    })
    var data = {"no_of_visited_customer": customerVisited,"no_of_fos": fosdata,"no_of_alerts": 15,"status":'success'};
    res.status(200).send(data);
    //return res.status(200).json({ status: true, data : _.pick(data )});
}
```

Here I need to send the response after the aggregation method execution. Here Before coming the db result the response is sending.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this,

```
var customerVisited=await Allocation.collection.aggregate([ 
    {$match:{}},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned.feedback_detail"},
    {$group:{
    _id:"total_feedback",
    count:{$sum:1}
    }
    }
    ])
    .toArray((err,docs)=>{
        if (!err) {
            customerVisited=docs
            console.log('custm',customerVisited);
        }else{
            console.log('err',err);
        }
    })
var data = {"no_of_visited_customer": customerVisited};
res.status(200).send(data);
```

But make sure the function in which this code is written is async (just add the word async before the word function), for example, if your function is,

```
function test() {
// some code
}
```

It should be

```
async function test() {
// some code
}
```

Comment: I have function like `module.exports.getDashboardDetail = (req, res, next) =>{}` and within it two aggregation are there.

Comment: Then it should be   
module.exports.getDashboardDetail = async (req, res, next) =>{}

Comment: here it returns `{
    "no_of_alerts": 15,
    "status": "success"
}` only.

Comment: Well that has to do with your aggregation stages, I can see the first stage itself is an empty match stage, wonder why it's there. I think you should put up a different question with your collection object structure and what you want the response to be, along with the aggregation you tried, to get the proper aggregation pipelines to use

Answer (score 0):

Why using toArray(err, docs) ?

```js
// use your paths to models
const Allocation = require('../models/Allocation')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports.getDashboardDetail = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    console.log('Inside dashboard controller');
    var customerVisited = await Allocation.collection.aggregate([ 
      {$match:{}},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list"},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list"},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list"},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned"},
      {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.loan_accounts_assigned.feedback_detail"},
      {$group: {
        _id:"total_feedback",
        count:{$sum:1}
        }
      }
      ])
      .toArray()
      var fosdata = await User.collection.countDocuments({})
      var data = {
        "no_of_visited_customer": customerVisited,
        "no_of_fos": fosdata,
        "no_of_alerts": 15,
        "status":'success'}
      res.status(200).send(data);
  } catch (e) {
    // if it is just a controller we can set status and send response
    // res.status(400).send(`Error ${e}`)
    
    // if using express middleware pass error to express with next(e)
    next(e)
  }
}
```